# get route showing null in response

Tags: javascript, sql, reactjs, typescript

I'm using TypeScript for making a GET request to get all members whose `isCore` is `true`. I've made several entries in the SQL database but it is showing `null` in `res.json`. Is the condition syntax is correct?

code:

```
router.get('/coreMem', async(req, res)=>{
  try {
    const core_member_details = await Member.findAll({
      where:{
        isCore: true
      }
    })
    
    res.status(200).json(core_member_details);
    
    }
   catch (err) {
    logger.error(`${err}`);
    res.status(500).send('Internal Server/Database Error!');
  }
 
});
```

Comment: Please include your code as text not as image.

Comment: did you `console.log(core_member_details);` ? You got expected results ? What package you are using to fetch records from db ?

Comment: What happens if you try a different query? For example, just to return all the records from your `members` table, without any conditions. This is just so you can verify that your DB connection is working properly, and that there are no problems in the back-end.

Answer (score 0):

I think that it, make sure that the Member model is correctly defined and that it is able to connect to the correct table in the database.

if not, a tip for you which is good debugging method:

To return all the records from the members table, you can use the findAll method without any conditions, like this:

```
router.get('/coreMem', async(req, res)=>{
try {
const all_member_details = await Member.findAll();

res.status(200).json(all_member_details);

},
catch (err) {
logger.error(${err});
res.status(500).send('Internal Server/Database Error!');
}
});
```